# Error when post back form: "Collection is read-only"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of 5 string values (possible answers for each question) which I want from user to type in. But when I submit form an error shows up: "Collection is read-only". What is wrong here?

Here is my view model:

```
public class QuestionVM
    {
        public QuestionVM() {
            PossibleAnswers = new string[5];
        }
        public QuestionVM(Question question) : this()
        {
            ID = question.ID;
            Text = question.Text;
            IsAssociatedWithProfessor = question.IsAssociatedWithProfessor;
            IsAssociatedWithAssistant = question.IsAssociatedWithAssistant;
        }
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithProfessor { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithAssistant { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
        public Question ToQuestion(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            Question question = new Question
            {
                Text = this.Text,
                IsAssociatedWithProfessor = this.IsAssociatedWithProfessor,
                IsAssociatedWithAssistant = this.IsAssociatedWithAssistant
            };
            //ID will be null if creating new question
            if(ID != null)
            {
                question.ID = (int) ID;
            }
            foreach (string possibleAnswer in this.PossibleAnswersVM.PossibleAnswers)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleAnswer))
                {
                    PossibleAnswer existingPossibleAnswer = context.PossibleAnswers.SingleOrDefault(ans => ans.Text == possibleAnswer);
                    if (existingPossibleAnswer == null)
                    {
                        PossibleAnswer ans = new PossibleAnswer { Text = possibleAnswer };
                        context.PossibleAnswers.Add(ans);
                        question.PossibleAnswers.Add(ans);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        question.PossibleAnswers.Add(existingPossibleAnswer);
                    }
                }
            }
            return question;
        }
    }
```

My post method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddQuestion(QuestionVM questionVM)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Question question = questionVM.ToQuestion(context);
                    context.Questions.Add(question);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Questions");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Trenutno nije moguće snimiti promjene, pokušajte ponovo.");
            }
            return View(questionVM);
        }
```

Part of view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PossibleAnswers, "PossibleAnswers")
```

And template:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PossibleAnswers";
}

@foreach (var str in Model)
{
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => str)
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not. Edit fields just don't appear when I run application.

Comment: Did your edit fix it or is there still a problem?

Comment: I added this: public QuestionVM() {
            PossibleAnswers = new string[5];
        } to my question view model, since I want 5 inputs from user to type in. It didn't render before because my list was empty. But now there is another problem, when I submit form an error shows up: Collection read-only.

Comment: A full stacktrace of the error might help.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6db7dbf520b4632c0bad Here is the error stacktrace

Comment: @bambiinela, I assume the comment to [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532029/editfor-for-list-of-string?noredirect=1#comment45379292_28532029) has solved this an some of your other recent questions. If that's the case either add your own answer and accept it or delete them so they don't get left in the unanswered queue.

Comment: I also suggest you stop mixing up responsibilities. A view model should contain only simple properties and not complex logic  e.g. `public string Text { get; set; }` The controller is responsible for mapping between data model and view model and you can use tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to help. In any case they should never reference your database context.

Comment: Ok, I will rearrange my code as you say. I was thinking about that, it seemed like a bad idea to reference database context in method for mapping between data model and view model, but I didn't know how else to check if there is existing possible answer in database... :S Thank you again.

Comment: I kept posting similar questions because  no one was answering and I was a bit frustrated :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed these tips:

1. Just add editor templates inside `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder
2. Use Parametrized templates by defining appropriate `@models` for application to detect more easy.
3. Guide razor with `[UIHint("TemplateName")]` where needed.

Take a look at [aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html).