# EditFor for List of string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want from user to input 5 strings (possible answers for question), so I have these elements in my question view model:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _possibleAnswers;
        public IEnumerable<string> PossibleAnswers 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _possibleAnswers ?? new List<string>();
            }
            set 
            {
                _possibleAnswers = value;
            }
        }
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PossibleAnswers";
}

@foreach (var str in Model)
{
       @Html.EditorFor(m => str, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Odgovor" })
}
```

But since PossibleAnswers list is empty, none of the edit fields show when I run the application. What do I need to change to display 5 edit fields and post them back correctly to controller?

Comment: Change the property to `public IEnumerable<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }` and add 5 `string.Empty` elements in the controller

Comment: Possible send a space character (" ") for each answer instead of blank?

Comment: Try `return _possibleAnswers ?? new List<string>{"", "", "", "", ""};`

Comment: Thank you all, it works fine now! Special thanks to @StephenMuecke, every answer he gives is helpful!

Comment: Also do not use `@foreach (var str in Model) { @Html.EditorFor(m => str) }` - it generates invalid html and duplicate name attributes (they all have `id="str" name="str"`). Its either `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i]) }` (the model needs to be `IList`) or just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)`

Comment: Again same mistake, invalid html code because of duplicate ids :D Ok, I will change that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return _possibleAnswers ?? new List{"", "", "", "", ""};
is solution.